# I noticed something in the optiboot bootloader hex file for Arduino. Why so?

Tags: arduino, avr, arduino-uno

When I look at the bootloader hex file, the starting address from the word type of the program is 7E00 according to intel-hex format. This is the 3F00. The interesting part starts right now. According to the Atmega328p datasheet, the BOOTS1 and BOOTS2 registers must be set for this to start from 3F00. But when I look at the Arduino Uno fuse settings,

```
lfuse = 0xff
hfuse = 0xde
efuse = 0x05
```

is defined as such. In this case . The BOOTS1 and BOOTS2 parameters in the High fuse settings parameter are set as not set.

Is there something I'm missing?

Here is the optibootbootloader.hex file

```
:107E0000112484B714BE81FFF0D085E080938100F7
:107E100082E08093C00088E18093C10086E0809377
:107E2000C20080E18093C4008EE0C9D0259A86E02C
:107E300020E33CEF91E0309385002093840096BBD3
:107E4000B09BFECF1D9AA8958150A9F7CC24DD24C4
:107E500088248394B5E0AB2EA1E19A2EF3E0BF2EE7
:107E6000A2D0813461F49FD0082FAFD0023811F036
:107E7000013811F484E001C083E08DD089C08234E0
:107E800011F484E103C0853419F485E0A6D080C0E4
:107E9000853579F488D0E82EFF2485D0082F10E0AE
:107EA000102F00270E291F29000F111F8ED06801E7
:107EB0006FC0863521F484E090D080E0DECF843638
:107EC00009F040C070D06FD0082F6DD080E0C81688
:107ED00080E7D80618F4F601B7BEE895C0E0D1E017
:107EE00062D089930C17E1F7F0E0CF16F0E7DF06D8
:107EF00018F0F601B7BEE89568D007B600FCFDCFD4
:107F0000A601A0E0B1E02C9130E011968C91119780
:107F100090E0982F8827822B932B1296FA010C0160
:107F200087BEE89511244E5F5F4FF1E0A038BF0790
:107F300051F7F601A7BEE89507B600FCFDCF97BE46
:107F4000E89526C08437B1F42ED02DD0F82E2BD052
:107F50003CD0F601EF2C8F010F5F1F4F84911BD097
:107F6000EA94F801C1F70894C11CD11CFA94CF0C13
:107F7000D11C0EC0853739F428D08EE10CD085E9AC
:107F80000AD08FE07ACF813511F488E018D01DD067
:107F900080E101D065CF982F8091C00085FFFCCF94
:107FA0009093C60008958091C00087FFFCCF809118
:107FB000C00084FD01C0A8958091C6000895E0E648
:107FC000F0E098E1908380830895EDDF803219F02E
:107FD00088E0F5DFFFCF84E1DECF1F93182FE3DFCA
:107FE0001150E9F7F2DF1F91089580E0E8DFEE27F6
:047FF000FF270994CA
:027FFE00040479
:0400000300007E007B
:00000001FF
```

Comment: Also asked at https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=626232

Comment: Are you sure there is the Optiboot? Not the default bootloader? Probably fuses just were set wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that this high fuse byte of the Arduino Uno is 0xDE; I confirmed that by checking [boards.txt](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/boards.txt).

That means that BOOTSZ is set to 11, which means the bootloader size is 256 words and starts at word 0x3F00 (byte address 0x7E00), as documented in the ATmega328P datasheet (Table 26-7).  There is no contradiction.

Comment: the confusion is that a fuse bit is called "set", if the value is zero and the online calculator applies this logic to BOOTSZ bits too

Comment: @Juraj Yes ,  The situation on the website is reverse logic. Unprogrammed means 1

Comment: I'm not sure which faulty online calculator you are referring to, but you don't need to use it.  Just convert 0xDE to binary, look at the value of the BOOTSZ bits, which is 11, then refer to the datasheet to learn what that means.  Please mark my answer above as the accepted answer by clicking the green the checkmark if it answers your question.